# How to call a class in android which implements Authenticator

Tags: java, android

I have created a sub class which is extended from `Authenticator` class. I am calling the `doInBackground` method from `AsyncTask` in this Authenticator class. The code is as follows

### TokenAuthenticator.java

```
public class TokenAuthenticator implements Authenticator {
    @Override
    public Request authenticate(Route route, Response response) throws IOException {
        try {
            Log.i("TokenAuth", "Testing");
            new AWSInitiator(AppSetting.getInstance().getApplicationContext()).execute().get();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ExecutionException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return response.request().newBuilder().header("Authorization", "Bearer " + AppSetting.getInstance().getSDKDataManager().getAccessToken()).build();
    }
}
```

This class is not called (Log is not printing). Here `AWSInitiator` is a class which `extends AsyncTask`

Answer (score 1):

I am using the below class which contains both authenticator as well as interceptor. You can remove the interceptor code if you only want the authenticator code.

**NOTE:-** I am using retrofit alongwith GSON in the below code

```
    class SupportInterceptor(context: Context) : Interceptor, Authenticator {
    var ctx: Context = context
    var prefManager: PrefManager

    init {
        prefManager = PrefManager.getInstance(ctx)
    }

    /**
     * Interceptor class for setting of the headers for every request
     */
    override fun intercept(chain: Interceptor.Chain): Response {

        var request = chain.request()
        request =
            request.newBuilder().addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json")
                .addHeader("Accept", "application/json")
                .addHeader(
                    "Authorization",
                    "Bearer " + prefManager.getString(PreferenceConstants.ACCESS_TOKEN)
                )
                .build()
        return chain.proceed(request)

    }

    /**
     * Authenticator for when the authToken need to be refresh and updated
     * everytime we get a 401 error code
     */
    @Throws(IOException::class)
    override fun authenticate(route: Route?, response: Response): Request? {
        if (response.code == 401) {
            val client = OkHttpClient()
            val jsonObject = JSONObject()
            val dataObject = JSONObject()
            dataObject.accumulate("userCode", prefManager.getString(PreferenceConstants.USER_ID))
            dataObject.accumulate("password", prefManager.getString(PreferenceConstants.PASSWORD))
            jsonObject.accumulate("Data", dataObject)
            val json = "application/json; charset=utf-8".toMediaTypeOrNull()
            val body = RequestBody.create(json, jsonObject.toString())
            val request = Request.Builder()
                .url(APIClient.COMPLETE_URL + "API ENDPOINTS")
                .post(body)
                .build()
            val res = client.newCall(request).execute()
            if (res.isSuccessful) {
                try {
                    val jsonObj = JSONObject(res.body?.string())
                    val accessToken = jsonObj.opt("accessToken")
                    val statusCode = jsonObj.opt("statusCode")
                    if (statusCode.toString().equals("-1") || accessToken == null || accessToken.toString().equals(
                            "null"
                        )
                    ) {
                        userLogout()
                        return null
                    } else {
                        prefManager.putString(
                            PreferenceConstants.ACCESS_TOKEN,
                            accessToken as String
                        )
                        return response.request.newBuilder()
                            .header("Authorization", "Bearer " + accessToken as String)
                            .build();
                    }
                } catch (e: Exception) {
                    return null
                }
            } else {
                return null
            }
        }
        return null
    }

    fun userLogout() {
        prefManager?.putBoolean(PreferenceConstants.IS_LOGGED_IN, false)
        val intent = Intent(ctx!!, LoginActivity::class.java)
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)
        ctx.startActivity(intent)
        ///ctx?.finishAffinity()
    }
}
```

And this is how you add it to your http client

```
httpClient.authenticator(supportInterceptor)
```

Comment: I am not familiar with Kotlin. Can you provide me a similar java version please

Comment: your java method of authenticator looks fine but it seems like you haven't added it to your http client

Comment: `OkHttpClient.Builder client = new OkHttpClient.Builder();
        TokenAuthenticator tokenAuthenticator = new TokenAuthenticator();
        client.authenticator(tokenAuthenticator);` I did like this

Comment: I think you need to add the interceptor too for authenticator to work

Comment: Will `.addHeader()` instead of `.header()` make any sense in the return statement of my TokenAuthenticator

Comment: But it will be called after your log gets printed and if you are adding header directly from authenticator it should be addHeader